# How to Select NULL when the column value is default value

Tags: python, mysql, select, mysql-connector

The table is set up for default value like below:

```
CREATE TABLE test {
    id          INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
    pname       VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
    strvalue    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '____', 
    numvalue    INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 2147483647, 

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `uidx_param` (`pname`,`strvalue`,`numvalue`)
};
```

I want to SELECT all the rows in the table and I want to convert default value to NULL in the result.

For example, if the following rows are saved in the table,

```
id  pname    strvalue  numvalue
1   'speed'  ____      20
2   'model'  'XG500'   2147483647
```

where strvalue takes a meaningless default value for the first record while for the second record, numvalue gets defaulted.

I want to select the result as

```
[{'id': 1, 'pname': 'speed', 'strvalue': NULL, 'numvalue': 20}, 
 {'id': 2, 'pname': 'model', 'strvalue': 'XG500', 'numvalue': NULL}]
```

where the default value '____' for 'strvalue' column is converted into NULL(None is good also). And 2147483647 to the NULL as it is default value without actual meaning.

Somehow, I think I should use DEFAULT function in SELECT statement.

How do I write the SELECT query to get the desired result?

---

I added the second row to the table because there was confusion on NOT NULL for the strvalue column. I want to use the table to save variables which can take string value or number value.

Comment: A bit confused by the decision to not allow `strvalue` to be null and then covert it to null in the query anyway.

Comment: @imbuedHope Thanks for the reply. I wanted to use the table to save number value or string value. I updated my question to add the second row to the table with string variable.

Comment: The cleanest way to do that would probably be to allow both fields to be NULL, and add a trigger during pre-insert and pre-update that causes an error if the entry is not valid. That way the select query stays sensible.

Comment: @imbuedHope If I allow NULL, the unique constraint would not work. Is it sensible to check uniqueness with trigger?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN strvalue='_____'
    THEN null 
    ELSE strvalue END
As strvalue, column2, column3...
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32485996)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how you want strvalue to return null when not set, I don't see the point in preventing it from being null, and instead defaulting it to something else.
Creating the table like this instead, would give you your desired output. You would however need to allow duplicate entries for strvalues.
Otherwise you could use a simple if statement to check if 'strvalue'=="____":

```
CREATE TABLE test {
id          INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
pname       VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
strvalue    VARCHAR(30), 
numvalue    INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 2147483647, 

PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `uidx_param` (`pname`,`numvalue`)
```

};

Comment: I want to use the table to save string variables or number variable. For example, the variable pname = 'model', strvalue  = 'XG500' will have numvalue as default. In this case, strvalue is not  null.